# Is there a way to loop through pandas dataframe and drop windows of rows dependent on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

1. **Problem Summary** - I have a dataframe of ~10,000 rows. Some rows contain data aberrations that I would like to get rid of, and those aberrations are tied to observations made at certain temperatures (one of the data columns).
2. **What I've tried** - My thought is that the easiest way to remove the rows of bad data is to loop through the temperature intervals, find the maximum index that is less than each of the temperature interval observations, and use the df.drop function to get rid of a window of rows around that index. Between every temperature interval at which bad data is observed, I reset the index of the dataframe. *However, it seems to be completely unstable!!* Sometimes it nearly works, other times it throws key errors. I think my problem may be in working with the data frame "in place," but I don't see another way to do it.
3. **Example Code:**
   Here is an example with a synthetic dataframe and a function that uses the same principles that I've tried. Note that I've tried different renditions with .loc and .iloc (commented out below).

```
#Create synthetic dataframe
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

temp_series = pd.Series(range(25, 126, 1))
temp_noise = np.random.rand(len(temp_series))*3
df = pd.DataFrame({'temp':(temp_series+temp_noise), 'data':(np.random.rand(len(temp_series)))*400})
#calculate length of original and copy original because function works in place.
before_length = len(df)
df_dup = df
temp_intervals = [50, 70, 92.7]
window = 5
```

From here, run a function based on the dataframe (df), the temperature observations (temp_intervals) and the window size (window):

```
def remove_window(df, intervals, window):
    '''Loop through the temperature intervals to define a window of indices around          given temperatures in the dataframe to drop. Drop the window of indices in           place and reset the index prior to moving to the next interval.
    '''
  def remove_window(df, intervals, window):  
     for temp in intervals[0:len(intervals)]:
        #Find index where temperature first crosses the interval input
        cent_index = max(df.index[df['temp']<=temp].tolist())
        #Define window of indices to remove from the df
        drop_indices = list(range(cent_index-window, cent_index+window))
        #Use df.drop
        df.drop(drop_indices, inplace=True)
        df.reset_index(drop=True)

    return df
```

So, is this a problem with he funtcion I've defined or is there a problem with df.drop?

Thank you,
Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be tricky to repeatedly delete parts of the dataframe and keep track of what you're doing. A cleaner approach is to keep track of which rows you want to delete within the loop, but only delete them outside of the loop, all at once. This should also be faster.

```py
def remove_window(df, intervals, window):  
    
    # Create a Boolean array indicating which rows to keep
    keep_row = np.repeat(True, len(df))
    
    for temp in intervals[0:len(intervals)]:
        # Find index where temperature first crosses the interval input
        cent_index = max(df.index[df['temp']<=temp].tolist())
        
        # Define window of indices to remove from the df
        keep_row[range(cent_index - window, cent_index + window)] = False
        
    # Delete all unwanted rows at once, outside the loop
    df = df[keep_row]
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    
    return df
```

Comment: I like this approach. In this formulation, will keep_row accumulate the windows of deletion for all iterations of the for loop? Or will it be overwritten every time the loop iterates?

Comment: This will accumulate the windows of deletion, because `keep_row` is initialised as all `True`, and in each iteration of the loop all the entries within the window are set to `False`. So in the end every row that fell in at least one of the windows, in any iteration of the loop, is deleted.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Beautiful! I missed the line that created the np.Series at first, and of course it didn't work. That is a nice way to accomplish this. Thanks!